# Fragments in reveal.js using Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, presentation, reveal.js

reveal.js supports fragments which will be shown one after another in HTML:

```xml
<section>
    <p class="fragment grow">grow</p>
    <p class="fragment shrink">shrink</p>
    <p class="fragment roll-in">roll-in</p>
    <p class="fragment fade-out">fade-out</p>
    <p class="fragment highlight-red">highlight-red</p>
    <p class="fragment highlight-green">highlight-green</p>
    <p class="fragment highlight-blue">highlight-blue</p>
</section>
```

It supports using Markdown instead of HTML for each slide using:

```
<section data-markdown>
    ## Page title

    A paragraph with some text and a [link](http://hakim.se).
</section>
```

But I could not find any documentation on using fragments with Markdown. Did I miss something or is it not yet supported?

Answer (score 34):

It support attributes now, by adding tag: `<!-- .element: class="fragment" -->`.

There are more attributes supported such as `background`, `index`, etc. See more examples on official doc: [Element Attributes](https://revealjs.com/markdown/#element-attributes), [Slide Attributes](https://revealjs.com/markdown/#slide-attributes).

Comment: But I don't understand the point; putting in these attributes is more work than just stepping out of Markdown for a while. Is there a shortcut? It's great this is feasible, but in the case of markdown, it is not helpful.

Comment: This is not working for me. All the things on the list just display at once.

Comment: OK, for some reason I have to wrap the list in `<script type="text/template">` as shown in the example in the documents. What is that about?

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking to create fragments inside a markdown formatted section as jez pointed out in his comment, this is what you need

```
* Item 1 <!-- .element: class="fragment" -->
* Item 2 <!-- .element: class="fragment" -->
```

Original source - https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/building-presentations-reveal-js/ (dead link)

There is another tutorial - http://htmlcheats.com/reveal-js/reveal-js-tutorial-reveal-js-for-beginners/

Comment: Updated info. Added another tutorial as a workaround.

Comment: Aaaand the second link is dead as well. :-(

Answer (score 5):

I am using pandoc to convert a markdown file into a reveal.js presentation.

Not sure why, but none of the above answers worked for me.  However, enclosing the text in a tagged fenced block did.

Using the reveal.js fragment examples https://revealjs.com/fragments/

```
:::{.element: class="fragment"}
Fade in
:::

:::{.element: class="fragment fade-out"}
Fade out
:::

:::{.element: class="fragment highlight-red"}
Highlight red
:::

:::{.element: class="fragment fade-in-then-out"}
Fade in, then out
:::

:::{.element: class="fragment fade-up"}
Slide up while fading in
:::
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This messes up with the nested lists for me

Answer (score 5):

For those using `pandoc` to produce slides from markdown,
be sure to read the manual
section on [slide shows](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#slide-shows)
and specifically,
the subsection on [incremental lists](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#incremental-lists).
Namely, the latter says you can:

- Use option `-i` for setting incremental behavior on all lists.
- Use *fenced div* syntax to force
  `incremental` or `nonincremental` behavior on a single list:

  ```markdown
  ::: incremental

  - Eat spaghetti
  - Drink wine

  :::
  ```
- Put a list inside a blockquote to reverse the preset behavior.

  ```markdown
  > - Eat spaghetti
  > - Drink wine
  ```

This does not give you the fine-grained control suggested on
[Clay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66014113/4244835),
but it is simple, documented, and compatible with multiple output formats.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. Clay's answer didn't play well with nested lists

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this issue [Markdown inside fragments](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/275), and I think
that fragments only apply to the HTML level.

I think you may manipulate the DOM after Markdown transformed directly, just like this:

```
{ src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js',
  condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); },
  callback: function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('section > p'), function(ele){ ele.className = 'fragment'; });
  }
},
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I think the OP's question must be about fragments-inside-markdown (i.e.: is there a markdown-like syntax that lets you create fragments inside a markdown-formatted section), rather than markdown-inside-fragments.   That's what I googled my way here for, too.